# Connecting an Asp.Net vNext site to an Orleans silo

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, orleans

I have an Asp.Net vNext site that I want to connect to a Silo. The vNext site is already done and in production, but the silo part isn't started yet. I'm just in the planning phase, so now's the time to just scrap the whole idea if it seems crazy. Is this even do-able?

I know that you can create a Virtual Network to connect your web app to your Worker Role, which seems simple enough. But, I'm not sure what my server and client configuration should look like, especially around using/discovering DeploymentIds.

The Orlean's provided AzureClient throws an exception when I try to use it in the vNext site -- something about an Azure-related type not being marked Serializable. In the vNext site, I can get the normal SiloClient to work by manually providing the DeploymentId. In my dev environment, the DeploymentId changes each time I debug, so this obviously isn't going to work.

Does anyone have any advice to point me in the right direction here? Let me know if you need more information, and I'll be glad to provide it you.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you hosting your vNext site ? Is it inside webrole or Azure App?
Orleans Client and Silo can't be run in the same App domain so the simplest way to run it in a separate worker role ( it also allows you to scale silos independently)

Comment: I'm hosting the vNext site in an Azure App, and I'm *planning* on hosting the Orleans Silo in a worker role. If you use the AzureHost in a worker role, it creates is own DeploymentId and publishes it to an Azure Table. The AzureClient will pick up connection info from that table, but I'm not able to use the AzureClient in my vNext site (see original post). I guess what's left is to go ahead and use a worker role for the silo, and write my own AzureClient -- inspired by the Orleans-provided one of course -- that'll work in my vNext site.